# NullPointerException on onListItemClick

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, listactivity, android-activity

I am getting a nullpointerexception randomly (i'm unable to reproduce the error consistently) in my ListActivity. StackTrace is showing an error on the first line, `super.onListItemClick()`. Not sure why this can return null?

```
@Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
        for (int i = 0; i < infos.size(); i++)
            if (i != position)
                l.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(0xFF444444);
        v.setBackgroundColor(0xFF666666);
        // v.setClickable(true);
        // test.setColorFilter(Color.parseColor("#444444"),
        // PorterDuff.Mode.DARKEN);
        ApplicationInfo ai = null;
        ai = infos.get(position);
        rinfos = findActivitiesForPackage(this, ai.packageName);
        ResolveInfo ri = rinfos.get(0);
        app_package_and_name = new String[] { ri.activityInfo.packageName, ri.activityInfo.name };
    }
```

Here is the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.sonrlabs.test.sonr.SONR.onListItemClick(SONR.java:189)
at android.app.ListActivity$2.onItemClick(ListActivity.java:319)
at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3763)
at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1936)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:867)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:625)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: You don't have the full stacktrace to post here?

Comment: because l or v is null. Full stacktrace please.

Comment: add the stack trace of the exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the line `super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);`

Comment: Removed. Crash still occurs unfortunately

Comment: Is stacktrace the same after removal?

Comment: error occurs at l.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(0xFF444444); not sure why it'd be out of bounds?

Comment: if you sure that's where the error occurs I would put a guard for "i" with a big LOG output beforehand - so next time it happens you catch it first

Comment: It's not out of bounds. You had a null pointer before and after the removal, so it must be "l" not "i". So I guess we have to look at the whole activity. This code works for a `ListActivity`. If you have a `ListView` but not a `ListActivity`, the listener is not correct. You'll have to use another listener like [this](http://markmail.org/message/2u22b72kpbikqwdd) listener.